# Where Can I find the LDAP server in a Spring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, ldap

I'm working on a large Spring MVC application, There is a probleme related the Parsing of the LDAP  file.
My question is: 
How can I find the LDAP server?
Where can find a good tutorial about using LDAP in a SpringMVC application?
Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply use LDAP server take a look at the official Spring-LDAP tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

In case you need embedded LDAP server, I'd recommend that you use embedded Apache DS : https://gist.github.com/arnobroekhof/6416762

See also: https://directory.apache.org/conference-materials.data/Alex_Karasulu_-_Workshop_Embed_ApacheDS.pdf

Comment: do not forget to upvote useful answers and mark the post as answer if it solves your problem